# Need Ruby binary tree implementation explanation

Tags: ruby, binary-tree

I came across a ruby binary tree implementation and would really love some clarification on some parts of the code, something I not seen before, with Enumerable.
I'm lost on what the #words method is doing with #entries? I looked up entries in ruby docs but still confused,  and the #insert_into method, how and where is the value of the node being stored in the @left, @right instance variables?

```
class Node
attr_reader :word, :count, :left, :right

include Enumerable

def initialize(word)
  @word, @count = word, 1
end

def size
  size = 1
  size += @left.size  unless left.nil?
  size += @right.size unless right.nil?
  size
end
def insert(another_one)
  case @word <=> another_one.word
    when 1
      insert_into(:left, another_one)
    when 0
      @count += 1
    when -1
      insert_into(:right, another_one)
  end
end

def each
  @left.each {|node| yield node } unless @left.nil?
  yield self
  @right.each {|node| yield node } unless @right.nil?
end

def words
  entries.map {|e| e.word }
end

def count_all
  self.map { |node| node.count }.reduce(:+)
end

def insert_into(destination, another_one)
  var = destination.to_s
  eval(%Q{
    if @#{var}.nil?
      @#{var} = another_one
    else
      @#{var}.insert(another_one)
    end
  })
end
```

Comment: This code is very good one for newcomers to explore in Ruby.. I think you could try by yourself.

Comment: Any assistance with what parts of the code is doing, specifically the insert_into method and words method. How and Where and What is entries???/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`entries` is from `Enumerable` and for reasons I cannot explain, the [documentation for `entries`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) is terrible. It appears to be roughly equivalent if not identical to `to_a`, using `each` to construct the array elements. With no explicit receiver specified, it's being sent to the current instance of `Node`.

As for `insert_into`, it's using Ruby's `eval` method which lets you interpret text as Ruby code at runtime. If you look at the string that's being passed to `eval`, you should be able to figure out what it does.